# No copy of IMGSGX535GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX535GLDriver found locally, reading from memory on remote device. This may slow down the debug session

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-developer-program

> Unable to read symbols for /Users/nishant/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Extensions/IMGSGX535GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX535GLDriver (file not found).
>   warning: No copy of IMGSGX535GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX535GLDriver found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.

Because of this error I can not login with the FBConnect login on the device (iPhone). It is working fine on the simulator. Other than that, everything is working fine when I press the FBConnect button then pop off the login page come and just gone away and say the above error.

If any one has the any idea, please let me know.